# Usar operador OR num CASE em PHP

Tags: php, operadores, switch

Como utilizar o operador `or` numa estrutura de controlo `switch`?

#### Exemplo

```
switch ($options) {
     
    case 1 || case 2:
        echo "Valor de opção 1 e 2";
        break;

    case 3:
        echo "Valor de opção 3";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não é possível o uso do `||` ou qualquer operador. Se precisar fazer isso, deve usar uma estrutura de `if`. O `switch` foi criado para comparação de valores de forma direta e individual, ele não pode ter expressões.

Mas dá para obter o que você quer neste caso específico já que ele é [*fallthrough*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough):

```
switch ($options) {
case 1:
case 2:
    echo "Valor de opção 1 e 2";
    break;
case 3:
    echo "Valor de opção 3";
    break;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/Fallthrough.php).

Como a execução dos `case`s vão ocorrendo em sequência, então basta você colocar um `case` sem especificar nada dentro dele, então o que for especificado em algum `case` posterior será executado por ele. Isso só é quebrado quando usa-se o `break`, que encerra todas as avaliações dos `cases`. Nesta construção, ao contrário do `if`, encerrar as avaliações deve ser feita de forma explícita.

Answer (score 8):

Para usar o mesmo comportamento em diferentes "cases", você deve escrever ele desta maneira:

```
switch($options) {
    //Observe que não dei um break no case 1, pois ele executará a mesma função do case2.
    case 1: 
    case 2: 
        echo "Valor de opção 1 ou 2";
        break;
    case 3:
        echo "Valor de opção 3";
        break;
    default:
        echo "operação default"; 
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As respostas existentes explicam bem este assunto, mas por questões "educacionais", vou deixar uma forma de utilizar a estrutura de controlo `switch` como se de um `if` se tratasse:

## `switch` com `OR`

Para podermos utilizar um `||` ou `OR`, temos que iniciar a nossa estrutura de controlo como booleana e em cada `case` fazer a comparação pretendida:

Ver no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/cptLCC).

```
$a = 3;

switch (true) {
  case ($a == 1 || $a == 2):
        echo "variável A é 1 ou 2";
        break;

    case ($a == 3 || $a == 4):
        echo "variável A é 3 ou 4";
        break;
}
```

<sup>O truque aqui é que estamos a passar uma expressão para o `switch` e a realizar a comparações com outra expressão.</sup>

É um método alternativo, que nos permite expandir a potencialidade desta estrutura de controlo, apesar de ir contra o propósito da mesma conforme descrito na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

> A instrução `switch` é similar a uma série de instruções `IF` **sobre a mesma expressão**.

No exemplo não estamos a fazer nada disto, tornando desta forma cada `case` num `if` sobre uma expressão diferente.

A conclusão é que esta é uma forma incorreta de lidar com a questão. Devemos utilizar a estrutura de controlo `if` para casos onde precisamos de fazer uso de operadores, pois a mesma foi desenhada para este efeito.

Answer (score 0):

Não é exatamente com um `switch`, mas a partir do PHP 8.0 você pode usar uma [expressão `match`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.match.php):

```
$options = 2;

$resultado = match ($options) {
    1, 2 => 'Valor de opção 1 e 2',
    3 => 'Valor de opção 3',
};

echo $resultado;
```

Veja [funcionando aqui](https://3v4l.org/YfBUS#v8.0.12).